Proving an interesting sequence
So a while ago I was learning about these sums, $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\frac{(n(n+1))^2}{4}$$
I wondered if I could find a general formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^{\alpha}=S_{n,\alpha}$$where alpha is a Natural Number, I started with $$\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)(k+2)...(k+(\alpha-1))=\phi=\dbinom{n+\alpha}{\alpha+1}\alpha!=S_{n,\alpha}+a_1S_{n,\alpha-1}+a_2S_{n,\alpha-2}+...+a_{\alpha-1}S_{n,1}$$
if you plug in a few values for alpha you get, $$\dbinom{n+1}{2}=S_{n,1}$$ $$2\dbinom{n+2}{3}-\dbinom{n+1}{2}=S_{n,2}$$ $$6\dbinom{n+3}{4}-6\dbinom{n+2}{3}+\dbinom{n+1}{2}=S_{n,3}$$ $$24\dbinom{n+4}{5}-36\dbinom{n+3}{4}+14\dbinom{n+2}{3}-\dbinom{n+1}{2}=S_{n,4}$$ $$120\dbinom{n+5}{6}-240\dbinom{n+4}{5}+150\dbinom{n+3}{4}-30\dbinom{n+2}{3}+\dbinom{n+1}{2}=S_{n,5}$$
How do you prove that this sequence of coeffciencts is A090582-OEIS with alternating neagtive signs?
THANKS

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers

@whatamidoing Did I just waste my time writing all this, and find sums? How do you find duplicate on this site

On a positive note, you practiced your latex, learnt something in the process of typing the question, and also you can find the duplicates by using the search bar in this website, [tag] (a key word related to your question), (+1 for your efforts)

Faulhaber-formula
